# How to find min value of an n digit number?

Tags: c#

I have been able to achieve what I am looking for but just want to know whether there is an inbuilt method to do so?

I have a number say 2665. Now since this is a 4 digit, I need the minimum value of a 4 digit number which is 1000.

Similarly if the number is 255, the answer would be 100.

I tried this

```
int len = 2665.ToString().Length;

string str = string.Empty;
for (int index = 0; index < len; index++) 
{
    if (index == 0) 
        str += "1";
    else
        str += "0";
}
```

This gives correct result of `1000`. But is there an inbuilt function for this?

Comment: I think 'vb.net' of your tag is not proper..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `Pow` and power 10 to length of string. For 1 it will give 1 for 2 it will give 10 etc.

```
var str = Math.Pow(10, len - 1).ToString();
```

Comment: It should be `var str = Math.Pow(10, len-1).ToString();`

Comment: I think it should be `len-1` to get the requested result

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Change answer like this: You can use `Pow` and power 10 to length of string. For 1 it will give 1 for 2 it will give 10 etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use constructor [String(Char, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of string to create the sequence of zeros you want.

```
string s = "1" + new string('0', str.Length-1);
```